# Iterating through sub-array to check dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an employee database with multiple sets of date values. Currently I output this data in this format:

```
<% @trainings.each do |training| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= training.birthday %></td>
    <td><%= training.comp_cert %></td>
    <td><%= training.cdl %></td>
    <td><%= training.forklift %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I would like to iterate through these dates on each loop and check the dates against

```
Time.now + 30.days
```

but am having some issues. I've tried this:

```
<% @trainings.each do |training| %>
  <% training.each do |t| %>
    <% if t < Time.now + 30.days %>
      <tr class="warning">
    <% else %>
      <tr class="success">
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <!-- Table Data Here -->

<% end %>
```

but it tells me there is no method called each on training. Is there a more efficient way of doing this rather than just manually checking each of the individual keys?

Comment: Do your training class object more attributes except those you mentioned in post ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't iterate on a single object. You can use the iterator pattern only on the collection. I suggest the following approach, for starters :)

```
<% @trainings.each do |training| %>
  <% %w{birthday comp_cert cdl forklift}.each do |field_name| %>
    <% if training[field_name] < Time.now + 30.days %>
      <tr class="warning">
    <% else %>
      <tr class="success">
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <!-- Table Data Here -->

<% end %>
```

Comment: I am getting an error when running the .each loop: 'undefined method `each' for #<String:0x007f9ad62057d8>'. I've doubled checked that all the field names match and spellings are correct. Am I missing a gem perhaps?

Comment: Nope, there is a typo in my anwser. It should be `%w{birthday comp_cert cdl forklift}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use helper

```
def old_training?(training)
  %{birthday comp_cert cdl forklift}.any? { |field| training[field] < Time.now + 30.days }
end
```

and in view:

```
<% @trainings.each do |training| %>
    <tr class="<%= old_training?(training) ? "warning" : "success" %>">

    </tr>
<% end %>
```